# CLIA Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for CLIA number. CLIA number is combination alpbh numeric without any spaces. Now i am using this expression `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{10}$/` am i using correct expression?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what is allowed. Does it always begin with "CLia"?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this....

**/^[a-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}$/**
^ this  is used to beginning of the line.
$ end of the line.
a-Z this will match the both cases.
this case will match the four alpha character and six numbers. so totally 10 alphanumbers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, it sounds like you want the first four characters to be "CLia" followed by 6 digits? If so, use `/^CLia\d{6}$/`. If not, be more specific.

Comment: That is just for example. we can use any character in any place for ex: 123456asdf, adfd123456

Comment: Then what strings are /not/ valid? Must there be four letters? Is it always four letters together?

Answer (score 0):

If your language support POSIX classes :

```
/^[[:alnum:]]{10}$/
```

Comment: Because it doesn't improve on the version the questioner gave. Even though he was totally unclear on what he wanted, I see no reasonable way in which that helps.

Comment: doesn't what ? he didn't provide any language !